# Is it possible to create a Path in Silverlight solely using data bindings?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, path

I would like to dynamically create a Path that is made up of several BezierSegments.

I would like to bind the data such that my data source only needs to provide numbers.
i.e. the app shouldn't create any geometry objects in the code.

Is this possible?

Update:

Here's an example for a fixed number of path segments:

```
<Path Stroke="Black">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint ="{Binding CalculatedPointA, Mode=OneWay}">
                <LineSegment Point="{Binding CalculatedPointB, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <LineSegment Point="{Binding CalculatedPointC, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <LineSegment Point="{Binding CalculatedPointA, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </PathFigure>
       </PathGeometry>
   </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

I'd like to have a variable number of segments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your actual question is:  No its not possible to bind data in such away to to dynamically create path figures or segements without using code (or using an additional component where some third-party has written code).

Is this question driven by the desire to not write code if not necessary or do have reason to believe that you shouldn't be?

Comment: I work in a pure MVVM setup so I try to avoid code behind and dynamically creating FrameworkElements in the ViewModels.

Comment: @elggarc: I hear that a lot.  MVVM can't perform magic, someone somewhere has to write code.  Is it your belief that MVVM precludes the creation of code?  If so on what do you base that?  I find that many adherents to the creed of MVVM don't properly understand its objectives.  In this case there is no good reason, MVVM based or not, why you should not write some code to deliver this purely visual component of your app.  This is handy because if there was a reason you'd be stuck with a methodology that outlaws doing something necessary.

Comment: Code in the view cannot be unit tested so we try, wherever possible, to keep the code in the view models and to kep the views pure XAML.  Obviously this is not always possible and we do have some view specific code in the views where it is unavoidable.

Comment: @elggarc:  Sometimes I think too much emphasis is made on this "but we can't unit test code in the view" thing.  Much complex hoop jumping then ensuse creating significantly more code than was actually needed too accomplish the requirement.   In some cases I suspect that the risks mitigated by the unit tests are nullified by the risks inherent in having excessively complex code.   Usually when something is purely visual in nature let the view handle it, just remember other good practices still apply such as creating re-usable controls.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the Data attribute on the Path element in XAML to a DependencyProperty of type String in your view model.  Use code to build a string representation of a Path statement: "F0 M 10,10 L100,10 A 1,1,1,1,110,10 L 200,10".

Here is the property:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly PathDataProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PathData", GetType(System.String), GetType(LineViewModel), Nothing)
    Public Property PathData As String
        Get
            Return Me.GetValue(PathDataProperty)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.SetValue(PathDataProperty, value)
            RaisePropertyChanged(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.Substring(4))
        End Set
    End Property
```

Here is the XAML:

```
<Path x:Name="PrimaryPath" 
          StrokeThickness="{Binding LineThickness, Source={StaticResource LineVM}, Mode=OneWay}" 
          Stroke="{Binding LineColor, Source={StaticResource LineVM}, Mode=OneWay}" 
          Data="{Binding PathData, Source={StaticResource LineVM}, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource myConv}}">
    </Path>
```

Download the StringToPathGeomertry converter from http://stringtopathgeometry.codeplex.com/..

You should be all set!